# How to get unique feature properties from geojson source in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've defined a mapbox [geojson](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-geojson) source:

```
map.addSource("places", {
    type: "geojson",
    data: "http://example.com/myfile.geojson",
});
```

My geojson source file has this structure:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "icon": "theatre"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-77.038659, 38.931567]
    }},

    {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "icon": "music"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-77.020945, 38.878241]
    }},
    ...]
}
```

I would like to get the *unique* names of the 'icon' properties (here: theatre and music). How can I loop over source to get these unique values? The objective here is to add a layer from these unique names for filtering purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I found [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/) the answer to my question. Basically, add a layer to the source, use mapbox function queryRenderedFeatures to get the features and then get unique features with the help of dedicated function getUniqueFeatures. After I can loop over uniqueFeatures to print the elements:

```
var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures({layers: ['my_layer']});
var uniqueFeatures = getUniqueFeatures(features, "icon"); 

uniqueFeatures.forEach(function(feature) {
        var prop = feature.properties;
        console.log(prop.icon);
})
```

The getUniqueFeatures function:

```
function getUniqueFeatures(array, comparatorProperty) {
    var existingFeatureKeys = {};
    // Because features come from tiled vector data, feature geometries may be split
    // or duplicated across tile boundaries and, as a result, features may appear
    // multiple times in query results.
    var uniqueFeatures = array.filter(function(el) {
        if (existingFeatureKeys[el.properties[comparatorProperty]]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            existingFeatureKeys[el.properties[comparatorProperty]] = true;
            return true;
        }
    });

    return uniqueFeatures;
}
```

Comment: NB: queryRenderedFeatures filters *features within map view* - so you will miss data if it isn't visible in the map view. i.e. `getUniqueFeatures` will return different data depending on the map position/zoom. In short you are not "looping over the source" - rather you are looping over the subset of currently visible features in the source. It should be noted that both `queryRenderedFeatures` and `querySourceFeatures` have this same limitation.

Answer (score 2):

We can use JavaScript [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object to store unique values.

```
const uniqueIcons = new Set();

const data = {}; // Your JSON data.

data.features.forEach((item) => {
  uniqueIcons.add(item.properties.icon);
});
```

**Example:**

```js
const uniqueIcons = new Set();

const data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "icon": "theatre"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-77.038659, 38.931567]
      }
    },

    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "icon": "music"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-77.020945, 38.878241]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "icon": "theatre"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-77.038659, 38.931567]
      }
    }
  ]
};

data.features.forEach((item) => {
  uniqueIcons.add(item.properties.icon);
});

for(let icon of uniqueIcons) {
  console.log(icon);
}
```

Comment: My data is not JSON, it's a mapbox source of type GeoJSON.

Comment: Even then it should work. Can you post some sample data so that I can test it?

Comment: @Patrick - Check out the example in my answer. You can run it to see the results.

Comment: my data is not geojson it's a mapbox source. See link in my edited question.

Comment: @Patrick - There is nothing special about geojson data format. JavaScript considers it as just another JSON object.

Comment: It's not geojson.

Comment: I found answer to my question (see edit). Thanks anyway @nikhil for your help.